# GLib-GObject-CRITICAL warnings

Tags: c++, c, gtk

I'm confused by these two warnings. Can anyone explain how I might have come about triggering them, and how they would be able to be debugged in gdb?

`` (gtkworkbook:24668): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_cclosure_new: assertion `callback_func != NULL' failed ``

(gtkworkbook:24668): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_closure_by_id: assertion `closure != NULL' failed

Comment: I get these all the time... quite annoying.

Comment: What usually was the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

This code was ported from an original implementation in C, and I had a requirement before to use an array of function pointers to call the functions inside of a shared library. Although this *[seemed]* to work at the time once I actually started using them it was not the case. I am a little stumped on why its not working, but I was able to centralized the problem to the following piece of code.

`gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (plugin()->workbook()->gtk_workbook), "switch-page",
 (GtkSignalFunc)this->signals[NOTEBOOK_SWITCHPAGE], plugin->workbook());`

Was changed to the following:

`gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (plugin()->workbook()->gtk_workbook), "switch-page",
 (GtkSignalFunc)signal_gtknotebook_switchpage, plugin->workbook());`

Now, the code compiles and I am not getting any nasty errors. I **think** this is the answer!

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can try is pass in --g-fatal-warnings to Gtk::Main, this will cause warnings to assert.  You can attach with gdb and maybe figure out some more detail about where this is failing.